# ssh claiming server using a different key when I try to log in using FQDN

Tags: ssh

I have a small Proxmox cluster.  As a result of this my /etc/sshd/ssh_known_hosts file looks like

```
<host1> ssh-rsa <key1>
<host1ip> ssh-rsa <key1>
<host2> ssh-rsa <key2>
<host2ip> ssh-rsa <key2>
```

If I access these servers using "ssh host1" all is well.

However, if I access them using "ssh -vvv host1.fqdn.org" first it asks me if I want to add a new key to known_hosts, and if I allow it, it throws the following error (log from a subsequent run where the key has been added to known_hosts)

```
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:<hash>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:18
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from host1.fdqn.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.37.20
debug1: Host 'host1.fdqn.org' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:18
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'host1.fqdn.ord' differs from the key for the IP address '192.168.xxx.xxx'
Offending key for IP in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts:2
Matching host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:18
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? ^C
```

This makes no sense to me.  There is only the one server with the one key running.  Is there anyway I can persuade ssh that no, really "host1" and "host1.fqdn.org" are the same machine and this is why they have the same IP?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for these options on the client (`~/.ssh/config`):

> `CanonicalizeHostname`
> Controls whether explicit hostname canonicalization is performed.  If set to yes then, ssh(1) will attempt to canonicalize the hostname specified on the command
> line using the `CanonicalDomains` suffixes and `CanonicalizePermittedCNAMEs` rules.

> `CanonicalDomains`
> When CanonicalizeHostname is enabled, this option specifies the list of domain suffixes in which to search for the specified destination host

```
Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'host1.fqdn.org' differs from the key for the IP address '192.168.xxx.xxx'
```

It seems odd if you get this *only* when connecting with the full name. As far as I get it, it should check the saved key for the IP regardless of the name used to connect to it. If the key used with the IP has changed, then you'll have to clear it with `ssh-keygen -R 192.168.xxx.xxx`. As far as I recall, it doesn't clear that itself, but keeps complaining every time you connect to a host having that IP.

That's probably on purpose, it can't know if the IP address was reused by someone with the proper rights to do it, or if something fishy was going on.